# Cannot re-order the blocks of Drupal 7 site

Tags: blocks

This error happens just on my local server (I use the last version of Acquia Dev Desktop, kind of XAMP for Drupal), not on our remote servers:

I am suddenly unable to re-order the blocks of our site (Drupal 7.23). The drag-and-drop functionality is not working and entering the weight numbers manually either. I have researched this problem and tried all solutions posted (Aggregate JS, disable LightBox2, change the DB block fields from tiny to INT...).

We have a large number of files in our website, and in some regions they have reached the magic number of 127. Reading a few posts, I see this may be the problem when you have some DB fields defined as tiny, but after changing all the tiny (4) fields of the blocks table to INT(11) I do not see any change.

Any clue?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: do you have any javascript errors? check console

Comment: And if not - any 4xx or 5xx HTTP errors? Something in watchdog or server's error.log?

Comment: Thanks Victor & Molot. The answer is no to both questions. A new piece of interesting evidence: this error happens just on my local server (I use the last version of Acquia Dev Desktop, kind of XAMP for Drupal), not on our remote servers.

Comment: When you say it is not working - what actually happens? Are you apparently able to save changes? Do you get a message? My guess is you may need to increase the PHP memory limit, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

If there's no javascript error in the console, and you have a lot of blocks, and are using the Suhosin extension, you may be hitting a Suhosin limit. If that's the case, you will need to increase the relevant values there. There may be more information in your server error log.

More info: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_vars

Comment: Thanks David. I have no idea about the Suhosin Extension, but your comment makes sense. This seems a problem associated with the web server, that in this case is Acquia Dev Desktop. This is what the php.ini says:
post_max_size = 1000M. Would you recommend to change this value? If yes, what would be your recommended value?

Answer (score 2):

Check your `max_input_vars` in php.ini If you have many blocks, this value may be exceeded leading to errors.

Try setting the value to 2000 (I had to use 5000 to cope with a specific site).

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding `php_value max_input_vars 2000` in **.htaccess** fixed the problem.

I had to put it between the `<IfModule mod_php5.c>` tags (which already existed) for it to work, like so:

```
# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_input_vars 2000
</IfModule>
```